# Firewall rule to drop DOS attacks. What is wrong with my command?

Tags: firewall, error-handling

I have a script like that :

```
MAXREQ='cat /var/log/maxreq_tmp'
DE=6
iptables -F
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp  -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp   -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount  $($MAXREQ) -j DROP

iptables -I INPUT -p tcp  -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
iptables -I INPUT -p udp   -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount  $($MAXREQ) -j DROP
```

I want make firewall rule to drop dos requests, but it shows error :

```
iptables: Invalid argument. Run `dmesg' for more information.
iptables: Invalid argument. Run `dmesg' for more information.
```

what is my command problem ?

Comment: What is in /var/log/maxreq_tmp ? And it appears you are using single ' rather then `

Comment: in  /var/log/maxx_req is maximum requests . for example 600

Comment: I thnk your problem is you are using single quotes, ' , rather then backticks ` you can also MAXREQ=$(cat /var/log/maxreq_tmp)